# findChild of QMenu does is not working properly

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmenu

findChild of QMenu is not working properly.

Following is the code for you

```
QMenu* lMenu;
QMenu* existingMenu = lMenu->findChild<QMenu*>(QString("A..."));
if (!existingMenu)
  lMenu->addMenu("A...");
```

I am getting the existing menu as NULL even if the menu for string A is already present

Answer (score 3):

The method `findChild()` searches for the objectName and not for the title, in your case the sub-menus do not have a name so it returns an empty list, so what you should do is filter the `QMenu`s first and then do a second filter with the titles:

```
#include <algorithm>

...

QString text("A...");    
// get sub-menus
QList<QMenu *> sub_menus = lMenu->findChildren<QMenu *>();
// filter by title
if(std::find_if(sub_menus.begin(), sub_menus.end(),
                [text] (QMenu *menu){ return menu->title() == text; }) == sub_menus.end())
{
    lMenu->addMenu("A...");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use [findChild](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild), have to consider `QMenu` as a `QObject`. Because the function is for searching the `QObject` but not `QMenu`.

**Demo:**

```
QMenu* menu = new QMenu;
QMenu* subMenu = new QMenu("subMenu", menu); // second parameter indicate menu is the parent qobject of subMenu
subMenu->setObjectName("subMenu object name"); // give submenu a qobject name for findChild 
menu->addMenu(subMenu);

if(menu->findChild<QMenu*>("subMenu object name") == subMenu) {
    qDebug()<<"Find subMenu";
}
```